# Is the maximum cardinality of a hom-set $2$? ($\emptyset$ and $1$)

Tags: category-theory

After reading this:

> A set of morphisms from object $a$ to object $b$ in a category $C$ is called
>   a hom-set and is written as $C(a, b)$ (or, sometimes, Hom$C(a, b)$). **So
>   every hom-set in a preorder is either empty or a singleton**. That
>   includes the hom-set $C(a, a)$, the set of morphisms from $a$ to $a$, which
>   must be a singleton, containing only the identity, in any preorder.

Source:http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/12/05/categories-great-and-small/

I agree with a preorder only being able to have $0$ or $1$, giving it a cardinality of $2$ (or $1$ if you don't count the empty set), but is it ever possible for any over category (e.g. no preorder like partial or total) to have more than $0$ or $1$ in a hom set?

Thanks

Comment: By definition, any category that's not a preorder has this property. For example, $\text{Set}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you read more carefully the source you give as a reference, you will find at least two examples.

**Example 1**. In the free category over the graph $a \xrightarrow{x} b \xrightarrow{y} a$, the set $C(a,a)$ contains infinitely many elements: $1_a$, $xy$, $xyxy$, $xyxyxy$, etc.

**Example 2**. Quoting your source:

> A monoid is a single object category. In fact the name monoid comes from Greek mono, which means single. Every monoid can be described as a single object category with a set of morphisms that follow appropriate rules of composition.

Thus the set of morphisms has the same size as the monoid.

**Exercise**. Prove the result stated by Qiaochu Yuan in his comment. If $C$ is a small category such that $C(a,b)$ contains at most one element for all objects $a$ and $b$, then the relation $\leqslant$ defined on the set of objects of $C$ by 
$$
\text{$a \leqslant b$ if and only if $C(a,b)$ is non empty}
$$

is a preorder.